# Why does jQuery.ajax follow redirects after POST calls?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http

The HTTP standard forbids to follow redirects after POST request without user confirmation. I issue a `jQuery.ajax` method POST request, which is answered by the server with a redirection.

The browser re-issues the request with the GET method? Why? Issuing a request with GET instead of POST normally doesn't make sense.

I tried this with Firefox 32.0.3

Comment: can you show us code?

Comment: You use ajax request with url that was not designed for ajax. Change url behaviour if you can

Answer (score 0):

Redirect after POST query is necessary to abort entering and resend information from user. For your task, you must to use status code 302 or 303 from server-side after your POST  query. If browser see such status code, redirect will not release!

Comment: Even though what you have written is in fact correct, the question by itself is more fundamental and addresses the RFC 2616 and browsers behaviour, not the use cases.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery depends on XmlHTTPRequest, and that automatically follows redirects, like it or not. (A feature request to allow more control in XmlHTTPRequest is now many years old, but apparently, the spec authors and browser vendors don't want to go there).

If you don't want the redirected request to use GET, you'll have to use HTTP status codes 307 or 308.